# How can I run the step debugger in vs code on a xunit Gherkin test?

Tags: visual-studio-code, xunit, vscode-debugger, gherkin

I can't find an option to debug xunit Gherkin test in vs code.

```
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Gherkin.Quick;
```

When I work with other xunit tests I can run the debugger directly from the test, including step debugging.

[image: Example of xunit debug in vs code]

But I can't find this option for Gherkin tests.

[image: Example of Gherkin test in vs code]